# Any solution to blend animator to another animator?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on 2 animators in a single character.

The reason I need to do this instead of using layers is that I have many different variables and states and layers.

These 2 animators work for different things at different times.

However, The problem came when I want to transition from animator1 to animator2.

Is there any solution to blend between animators?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may consider to use https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html

**Blend Trees**

> A common task in game animation is to blend between two or more similar motions. Perhaps the best known example is the blending of walking and running animations according to the character’s speed. Another example is a character leaning to the left or right as it turns during a run.

Comment: Hmm, I still not get how Blendtree can solve my problem, My animator controller has different variables and logics, That's why I want to separate them in to two.

Comment: Also you may read [https://forum.unity.com/threads/performance-of-separate-animators-vs-single-multilayer-animator.428234/#post-2769274](https://forum.unity.com/threads/performance-of-separate-animators-vs-single-multilayer-animator.428234/#post-2769274) it's recommended to use only one animator per hierarchy. I think unity does not support blending between multiple animators so if you really want to achieve this feature you may implement it.

Comment: May [Animation Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationLayers.html) can suit to your question?